# When I add <br> in a textfield it is taken as a command not a string

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

The below code take the string written in the textfield and put it inside the def div. When testing, if I entered (as a string inside the textfield) it is taken as command. It is not writing in the def div

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function add() {
            var inp = document.getElementById("text").value;
            alert (inp);
            document.getElementById("def").innerHTML += inp;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="text"></textarea><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="add()">submit</button> 
    <div id="def"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am trying to write <br> inside the textarea but it does not appear. it is taken as a command

Comment: `<textarea id= "text"></textarea> <br>` check this statement again. there 's a `"` that you didn't see

Answer (score 2):

Provided that the extra **`"` is just a typo in the question** you can write it as **`&lt;br&gt;`**.

- **`&lt;`** is **`<`**
- **`&gt;`** is **`>`**

If the extra **`"`** is a typo **found in your code as well**, you'd better remove it before trying anything else.

---

In Javascript, **in order to prevent the parsing of HTML content** in **`textarea`** and **`input`** elements, you can use **`innerText`** instead of **`innerHTML`** as shown below:

```
document.getElementById("def").innerText // instead of innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
document.getElementById("def").innerHTML += inp;
```

with

```
document.getElementById("def").textContent += inp;
```

to prevent processing the html tags